# Filter Product Collection by BOTH multiple catgeories

Tags: category, collection, product-collection, collection-filtering

In my magento store i need to filter my product collection by 2 categories.

I have searched online and found ways of doing this (see existing code below) but they filter multiple categories using an `OR` condition – is there any way to do this with an `AND` condition so the products have to be found in BOTH categories not just any of them?

I am currently using the code below:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => '26'),
        array('finset' => '63'))
    )
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

    foreach($_productCollection as $_product){
        echo $_product->getName()."<br/>";
    };
```

My product/category setup is:

products:

```
category 1 (ID 26)
category 2 (ID 63)

product A - found in category 1
product B - found in category 1 & 2
product C - found in category 1 & 2
```

So my current code below would output all 3 products where as i want it to only show products B and C

Answer (score 1):

Ended up filtering by just the 1 category, and then on the for each output checking if the product id is present in the 2nd category. Not ideal but does the job for now

```
$_filter = 26;

foreach($_productCollection as $_product){
    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if (in_array($_filter, $cats)):
        ....
    endif; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the category_product_index table with both category ids and then filter by `count()=2` (i.e. only show products that are present in both categories):

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$categoryIds = [ /* Category IDs */];
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$joinConditions = array(
    'cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id',
    $productCollection->getConnection()->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id IN (?)', $categoryIds),
    $productCollection->getConnection()->quoteInto('cat_index.store_id=?', $storeId)
);
$productCollection->getSelect()->join(
    array('cat_index' => $this->getTable('catalog/category_product_index')),
    $joinConditions,
    array('cat_index_position' => 'position')
);

$productCollection->getSelect()->columns(
    array('category_count' => 'COUNT(cat_index.category_id)')
);
$productCollection->getSelect()->having('COUNT(cat_index.category_id) = ?', count($categoryIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using the following AttributeFilter:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => array($newArray))));
```

$newArray is an array containing the category_id's as values.

**EDIT**
What if you tried this:
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array("in"=>array('26')));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array("in"=>array('63')));

According to [Magento documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) this should provide an AND clause.
You can always dump $collection->getSelect(); to view the SQL query and debug from there.

Comment: I've just tried the following with your code and i get the same result, is this correct - ?                                                                      $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => array($newArray))));

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? You get the same result as in, you still got all three products?

Comment: Yep all 3 are coming up still. My code in the comment above is a little messy as i couldn't format it as a block, are you able to adapt that line into my code so i can check it's not my mistake

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I've tried the edit and still no luck. I've tried several variations as shown below in the links, with the outcome/result also below each one, can you show where abouts and how that line fits in with me existing code?:                               http://pastebin.com/zGeP9XW5                                       http://pastebin.com/Jrnb2bm2

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, see the pastebin for the complete code.

Comment: Sorry Patrick I cannot see your pastebin link...

Comment: Try this link: http://pastebin.com/yx87EAnR

Comment: hmm very odd i've just tried your code and i get no errors but no output either. When i do a for each with getName, getId etc nothing outputs. I've also tried `var_dump($_productCollection->getSize());` and it comes up as `int(0)` suggesting empty?

Comment: What if you apply only 1 attributeFilter? Do you get a result then? Another possible way to resolve this would be to get the products in a certain category, store their product id's in and array. Then get the products in another category and store their id's in an array. Then compare the two arrays and select any product id's that are in both arrays. Not very 'neat' code, but it does the trick I guess.

Comment: Ended up doing something similar but just checking an array in the for each loop (see answer above). thanks for your help on this though